# How can i display json directly from rails controller(without view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to render json similar to:

```
{
success:0,
error:"No money specified";

}
```

Now I can do this in a seperate view, but i was wondering if there is any way of directly showing this json and bypassing the biew. On a related note, can i directly dump a string to ouput(instead of the view) in rails. I am using 4.0, but should be generic enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following line directly in your controller

```
    render :json => {success: 0, error: "No money specified"}
```

For more on this, you can look at the doc for respond_to: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html